# How do i make a brick wall?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm kinda new to blender and I'm trying to replicate a living room for studying reasons.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZkD0.jpg

The wall in question lies in the right side of the room along with some windows and I do have a PBR material that fits my needs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2mrs.jpg (texture I'm trying to use)

I've tried a bunch of stuff, but none worked the way I thought it would. I tried using modifiers subdivision surface + displace with texture I mentioned above and I created a material along with the provided textures, but the material was too flat for my liking and I was having a really hard time unwrapping the mesh and in the end it became a mess.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: If making flat walls, a good set of PBR textures should be enough. For more complex brick work (archways, rounded structures, etc), you might want to create a particle system of brick objects. You can use both techniques together, texturing the particle bricks to match (using the same PBR textures). If you have to cover really large walls, breaking up the texture uniformity can present a challenge, but there are ways around this such as cutting and rearranging chunks of the (already UV mapped) wall geometry, or peppering particle bricks over the textured wall in strategic spots.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the PBR material that you are using is quite poor if the image you uploaded is what you're using. I would try something along these lines:

[image: Sphere 1]
[image: Sphere 2]
[image: Sphere 3]

These were found on the popular site [Poliigon](https://www.poliigon.com/).

You can probably get away with only using the normal maps and displacement.

As far as unwrapping, I'm not sure what you have to unwrap exactly. It's a wall... just unwrap it like you would any other rectangular object and try to hide seams where possible.